# WYSIWYG editor (á la Android Studio, Qt Designer, ...) for building Electron apps?

Tags: react, electron

I'm flirting with using Electron for building desktop apps in the future. Has anyone encountered a tool for building Electron apps work similar to Android Studio or Qt Designer, *in that you don't have to write a single detail about styling the pages, and can just drag and drop UI components*? Thanks for any input!